# Need to add second line value to the first if second line Cost = 0

Tags: c#

I have a strange situation here. I have that table structure

[image]

Whenever Cost is 0 I need to put Line 2 description together with Line 1 description.

I should get this at the end

[image]

I am trying to do this in c# but failing miserably.

So far, this is where I am at

[image]

Comment: Please describe your problem in depth sufficient enough that we can understand what you're doing, how you're currently doing it, and what the issue with that approach is. Provide code samples or a [mcve] as necessary.

Comment: You need to look into parsing, if all your information is split into groups of 3 words (Line, Number, Quantity) you can split by white space, if not, you would need to come up with something more fancy, probably through a regular expression. 
Also, what happens if the first item also is 0?

Answer (score 1):

The following works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("Desc", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Cost", typeof(int));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Line 1", 200 });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Line 2", 0 });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Line 3", 0 });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Line 4", 500 });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Line 5", 0 });

            DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone();

            string description = "";
            int total = 0;
            int cost = 0;
            int rowNumber = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.AsEnumerable())
            {
                string newDescription = row.Field<string>("Desc");
                cost = row.Field<int>("Cost");

                if ((++rowNumber == 1) || (cost == 0))
                {
                    description += " " + newDescription;
                    total += cost;
                }
                else
                {
                    dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { description, total });
                    total = cost;
                    description = newDescription;
                }
            }
            if (total != 0)
            {
                dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { description, total });
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, a simple `foreach` should *group* the items of `_financials`:

```
List<Financials> _financials = ...

...

List<List<Financials>> groups = new List<List<Financials>>();

foreach (Financials item in _financials) 
  if (item.cost != 0 || groups.Count <= 0) 
    groups.Add(new List<Financials>() {item})
  else  
    groups[groups.Count - 1].Add(item);
```

Then you can print the `groups` out:

```
using System.Linq;

...

foreach (var group in groups)
  Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(" ", group.Select(item => item.description))} {group.First().cost}");
```

If you want to turn `groups` into `List<Financials>`:

```
var compressedFinancials = groups
  .Select(group => new Financials() {
     description = string.Join(" ", group.Select(item => item.description)),
     cost        = group.First().cost,
   })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: There is no GROUPs in the tables.  You code doesn't work because the first row will be byiteself.  the OP want the first row and the next two zeroes in the same group.

Comment: @jdweng: thank you! Is should have been `groups[groups.Count - 1].Add(item);` adding zero `cost` item to the *last* group